# What is the difference between clustering and matching?

Tags: algorithm, cluster-analysis, graph-algorithm, matching

What is the difference between clustering and matching?

For example: There's a pool of four elements and in the one scenario I want to generate pairs. What I do is I measure the distance of each element to each other which yields a 2x2 matrix. Then the matching algorithm finds the two pairings with the lowest or highest weighted sum.

What is a clustering algorithm doing? When I demand a cluster number of two then the result is the same, or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specifying the number of elements in a cluster (pairs for example) doesn't make much sense. If you have been looking at `k-means` (`k-medoids`), the `k` actually indicates how many clusters will be created in total. So, if you have 4 elements and use `k = 2`, you can get one cluster with 1 element and another cluster with 3 elements, depending on the data you have. Anyway, clustering on 4 elements doesn't make sense.

Comment: Thanks! I thought by having a small number of elements makes it easier to understand. Finally a clustering algorithm obtains the number of clusters itself?

Comment: Hierarchical Clustering obtains the number of clusters itself, while for k-means you need to specify the number of clusters k upfront. Those 2 are the most popular (basic) clustering algorithms.

Comment: Thanks! But when I force k=2 for k-means then I get maybe the same as in case of matching (probably depending on the conditions to the clustering)?

Comment: Maybe in some cases, but not guaranteed. If you have 4 points [(1, 1), (100, 100), (99, 100), (100, 99)] and use Euclidean distance, then eventually the first point will be alone in one cluster and the last 3 points will be in the another cluster.

Comment: Ok, got it. Thank you!